# iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to configure iptables to get [Redsocks](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks) working {purpose is to get system wide socks proxy}

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create new chain
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8888
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner USER -j REDSOCKS
```

I get the following

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

i think what causes this is -j REDIRECT --to-ports e.g when i try

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 8888
```

still gives me that

And using this i can get redsocks work but it redirects everything to 127.0.0.1:8888 , e.g when i open google.com it goes to 127.0.0.1:8888 but url stays google.com

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -o eth0 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8888
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDSOCKS
```

and here is my redsocks.conf

```
base {
        log_debug = on;
        log_info = on;
        daemon = on;
        log = "file:redsocks.log";
        redirector = iptables;
}
redsocks {
        local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
        local_port = 12345;
        ip = 127.0.0.1;
        port = 8888;
        type = socks5;
}
```

Comment: Don't do iptables by running the `iptables` command per rule. It's terribly inefficient. Use `iptables-restore` instead.

Comment: Maybe your kernel doesn't have `REDIRECT`? Are you able to do `modprobe ipt_REDIRECT` to manually load the module? By the way, there is no need for `#!/bin/bash` since you do not use any bashisms in your script. `#!/bin/sh` will do just fine.

Comment: Run your script with `sh -x script`, it will show you the lines which causes the messages. If you omit the REDIRECT target ip, the port needs to be `:8888`.

Comment: @Celada thanks for the clue [link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-3.html)

Comment: @ott nice trick sh -x is very nice